# "Invalid replication factor" in confluent Kafka Go Client

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-go

Im new to kafka, and trying to get started with my project. I have this in my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Then im running my main.go file which has both producer and consumer and also some mock topic.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
)



func main()  {
    topic := "HVSE"
    p, err := kafka.NewProducer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
        "client.id": "foo",
        "acks": "all",
    })
    go func() {
        consumer, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
            "bootstrap.servers":    "localhost:9092",
            "group.id":             "foo",
            "auto.offset.reset":    "smallest",
        })

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        err = consumer.Subscribe(topic, nil)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        for {
                ev := consumer.Poll(100)
                // fmt.Println(ev)
                switch e := ev.(type) {
                case *kafka.Message:
                        fmt.Printf("consumed message from queue: %s\n", string(e.Value))
                case *kafka.Error:
                        fmt.Printf("%v\n", e)
                        // return
                // default:
                //      fmt.Printf("Ignored %v\n", e)
                }
        }
    }()

    deliverch := make(chan kafka.Event, 10000)
    for {
        err = p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
            TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
            Value: []byte("FOO"),
        },
            deliverch,
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    
        <- deliverch
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the default, I get into it.

Otherwise i got this error in console.

```
2023/09/26 13:45:05 Broker: Invalid replication factor
exit status 1
```

My kafka and zookeeper containers are running.

I changed the docker-compose.yml file, but that didn't help. And I found that my consumer.Events() is nil, but I can't understand why this is the case

Comment: Just search for the error message as a start: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Broker%3A+Invalid+replication+factor.

Comment: How many partitions does have the topic HVSE? Did you create it manually before starting your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your code and it is correct but the problem in the compose.yml only adjusts the ADVERTISED_LISTENERS

Instead of this:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
```

Use this:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```